# Could not execute a function on UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, swift

Whenever i touch on the screen nothing happens. looks like `handleDismiss()` function is never fired. Does anybody knows what is the real problem here.

```
import UIKit

class SettingLauncher : NSObject{

    let blackView = UIView();

    func showSettingMenu(){
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{

            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0, alpha: 0.5);
            blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true;
            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: #selector(self.handleDismiss)));

            window.addSubview(blackView);
            blackView.frame = window.frame;
            blackView.alpha = 0.1;

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
                self.blackView.alpha = 0.5;
            }
        }
    }

    func handleDismiss(){
        print("Touch recognised");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that tapping at that place on the screen triggers the gesture recognizer?.. You're sure that nothing else is swallowing up the event?

Comment: I am not sure why the handleDismiss function is not firing. All the code is shown above and nothing is eating the event.

Comment: yes nothing happens with the above code. If i change the target to blackView then i get a bunch of error while tapping. But when i change to self or nil then nothing is printed on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the above error because I called the function showSettingMenu() through another class function as below:-

```
func handleMoreSetting(){
        let settingLauncher = SettingLauncher();
        settingLauncher.showSettingMenu();  // Call SettingLauncher class
    }
```

The problem went away when I declared settingLauncher as global instance like below.

```
let settingLauncher = SettingLauncher();
func handleMoreSetting(){
        settingLauncher.showSettingMenu();  // Call SettingLauncher class
    }
```

Do anybody knows why the problem occured? In both cases, I am calling the same function but with a different result.

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the `UITapGestureRecognizer` which class will be handling the response - not just which function, but which class

Change

```
blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: nil, action: #selector(self.handleDismiss)));
```

To

```
blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleDismiss)))
```

Here's an example which I have working.  I am initiating the view from a button - I don't know how yours is started, but that shouldn't matter

```
class ViewController: UIViewController
{
    let blackView = UIView()

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func handleDismiss(){
        print("Touch recognised");
    }

    @IBAction func cmdDoOtherStuff(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow{

            blackView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.5)//(r: 0, alpha: 0.5)
            blackView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            blackView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleDismiss)))

            window.addSubview(blackView)
            blackView.frame = window.frame
            blackView.alpha = 0.1
             UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
             self.blackView.alpha = 0.5;
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens when I change the target to self also.

Comment: oh - I see you're calling this from a class of `NSObject`  You need to put this code in the UIViewController which contains the view, or pass in a reference to the UIViewController, and move the `handleDismiss` function there

Comment: The result is same as above. Nothing changes if it to UIViewController also.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. When i moved the whole class to another class then it worked well.